# Cannot find symbol - method guess()

Tags: java, compiler-errors

Im really new to java and im struggling to understand the basics. Because of this I cant understand why this wont compile.

The error is appearing on the `int guess = input.guess();`and it says it cannot find symbol - method guess().

Thanks in advance for any help

```
public class HiLo
{
    private int upper;
    private int randomNumber;
    private Input input;
    private boolean won;
    private int guesses;

    public HiLo(int x)
    {
        upper = x-1;
        randomNumber = (int)(Math.random() * upper)+1;
        input = new Input();
        won = false;
        guesses = 10;
    }

    public void playHumanGame()
    {
        while ((won == false) && (guesses > 0))
        {
            int guess = input.guess();
            guesses--;
            if (guess > randomNumber)
            {
                System.out.println("You're too high pal");
            }
            else if (guess < randomNumber)
            {
                System.out.println("You're not high enough");
            } 
            else 
            {
                System.out.println("You won the game... Well done I suppose...");
                won = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not into Java but... does the class `Input` have such public method?

Comment: This appears to be a common learning tutorial. It would help if we know which one / where this sample code is coming from.